# How to get ordered Channels detail responce from Youtube Channel Api

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

i am building an app using Youtube API. I want to show Channel Profile pictures on my app but when i request for list of channel lists i always get unordered list of channels.
Here's my Get Request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCjmJDM5pRKbUlVIzDYYWb6g,UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA,UCt5A35uhB3dVf-KFGCOyqtA,UCyFbHB68DazkUxdq2WvPDfQ,UCYLeUhjZvudIF3mPYknrQBw&part=snippet&key=MY_API_KEY
```

But the response i recieve is not in order as channel ids in the get request.

How do i get ordered list of channels same as the position of ids in the get url?

Comment: Does Google specify that the channels provided by the API will be in a certain order? If not, then you'll have to reorder them yourself.

Comment: no they didnt specify. they just told that the multiple channel ids will be comma seperated and thats it. i have arranged multiple times these 5 channel ids but get the same unsorted result in response

Comment: I think you're stuck with writing your own logic. See Bharath's answer. I doubt that Google care about this.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two different approaches for this issue.

**Without** Javascript:

1. Make separate GET requests for each channel ID.
2. Push every response into an array. (Don't forget that the requests are asynchronous and so you need to make them synch by setting the `async` option in the GET request to `false`. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) at MDN).

This approach obviosly multiplies the network traffic by `n` times for n number of channel ids. It also eats up your request 'quota' linearly.The only positive side is, you are getting the resultng list in which you requested it.

**With** Javascript:

1. Sort the channel IDs first.
2. Make the GET request.
3. Sort the resulting string again.

So whatever the order you requested your channels is the order you get (After sorting the result ofcourse). The benefit here is that you are making a single GET request. Also, the computation is done on the client side. So unless you are sorting like 10,000+ items, I don't think it adds any significant/visible overhead to your app.

Good luck and don't forget to post your decision with the reason why.

Comment: Well your idea is good and i will choose The With Javascript method by sorting the data that i received from Youtube api.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my solution worked out for you, please mark it as the answer. It will help build my reputation.